# Saving multiple pandas dataframes to Excel file with Styleframe, each one on a different sheet

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-excel, styleframe

I am trying to save a number of pandas dataframes to excel. I want them all in the same excel file, but with each one on a different sheet.

This is what I have at the moment. This is just saving all my dataframes to separate files. I have used `StyleFrame`. Some of the values in these dataframes have `\n`. When I write to excel, I want it to register this as a new line within each cell.

Using `StyleFrame` was the only solution I could find.

```
file_path = "path_to_save_files"
StyleFrame(df1).to_excel(file_path + '/df1.xlsx').save()
StyleFrame(df2).to_excel(file_path + '/df2.xlsx').save()
StyleFrame(df3).to_excel(file_path + '/df3.xlsx').save()
```

This is what I've tried. This would normally work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file_path}/output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

StyleFrame(df1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "sheet1")
StyleFrame(df2).to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "sheet2")
StyleFrame(df3).to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "sheet3")
```

However, because I'm using `StyleFrame`, I get an error:

> AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'sheet_view'

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any particular reason you are using `xlsxwriter` as an engine? `styleframe` only supports `openpyxl`, so this will work:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file_path}/output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[2]})
StyleFrame(df1).to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet1")
StyleFrame(df2).to_excel(writer, sheet_name="sheet2")

writer.save()
```

**Note that you do have to explicitly call `writer.save()`** (just like when working with `pandas.DataFrame` directly).

There is a shortcut for `pd.ExcelWriter(f'{file_path}/output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')`:

```
writer = StyleFrame.ExcelWriter(f'{file_path}/output.xlsx')
```

Comment: Perfect thank you. The reason I used `xlsxwriter` is mainly because that's all I could find when I initially put my script together. I likely just need to do a lot more reading on what `xlsxwriter` and `openpyxl` are.